# Using Array.map in nested object structure in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below object structure in array

```
[
  {
   "modules":set of modules here 
   "details": [
     {
       "name":"abc"
       "version":"1.2.3"
     },
     {
       "name":"def"
       "version":"2.3.4"
     },
     {
       "name":"ghi"
       "version":"4.5.6"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "modules":set of modules here 
   "details": [
     {
       "name":"jkl"
       "version":"7.8.9"
     },
     {
       "name":"mno"
       "version":"10.11.12"
     },
     {
       "name":"pqr"
       "version":"13.14.15"
     }
   ]  
  }
]
```

What I want to do is :
get details array transformed into below format for each root object in master array as

```
"details": [
     {
       module:"jkl:7.8.9"
     },
     {
       module:"mno:10.11.12"
     },
     {
       module:"pqr:13.14.15"
     }
   ]
```

So final array would be :

```
[
  {
   "modules":set of modules here 
   "details": [
     {
       "module":"abc:1.2.3"
     },
     {
       "module":"def:2.3.4"
     },
     {
       "module":"ghi:4.5.6"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "modules":set of modules here 
   "details": [
     {
       "module":"jkl:7.8.9"
     },
     {
       "module":"mno:10.11.12"
     },
     {
       "module":"pqr:13.14.15"
     }
   ]  
  }
]
```

What I have tried and is working is :

```
rootArray.forEach((entry)=> {
    let line = entry.details.map((detailEntry)=>{
    //merge detailEntry into single line 
    })
    entry.details = line 
});
```

My question is : is this a right approach or is there any better solution available ?

Comment: looks right - it does what you want ... all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `map`s is probably the right approach. It will return a *new* array rather than mutating the original array.

`map` over the main data array, and then assign the result of mapping over `details` to the `details` property of the object that you're returning on each iteration.

```js
const data=[{modules:"set of modules here",details:[{name:"abc",version:"1.2.3"},{name:"def",version:"2.3.4"},{name:"ghi",version:"4.5.6"}]},{modules:"set of modules here",details:[{name:"jkl",version:"7.8.9"},{name:"mno",version:"10.11.12"},{name:"pqr",version:"13.14.15"}]}];

const out = data.map(obj => {
  return {
    modules: obj.modules,
    details: obj.details.map(detail => {
      const { name, version } = detail;
      return { module: `${name}:${version}` };
    })
  };
});

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
   "modules": "set of modules here",
   "details": [
     {
       "name":"abc",
       "version":"1.2.3"
     },
     {
       "name":"def",
       "version":"2.3.4"
     },
     {
       "name":"ghi",
       "version":"4.5.6"
     }
   ]
  },
  {
   "modules": "set of modules here",
   "details": [
     {
       "name":"jkl",
       "version":"7.8.9"
     },
     {
       "name":"mno",
       "version":"10.11.12"
     },
     {
       "name":"pqr",
       "version":"13.14.15"
     }
   ]  
  }
]

const result = data.map( item => ({modules: item.modules, details: item.details.map(i => {
  return { module: `${i["name"]}:${i["version"]}` }
})}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Mina, no documentation, no links to documentation, no comments in the code to explain how it works? Code dumps are kinda frowned on here.

Answer (score 1):

your approach seems correct.

there is another way to achieve the expected structure, making the copy of the initial array however instead of modifying the existing.

```
const result = rootArray.map(({ details, ...rest }) => ({
    details: details.map(/*transform*/),
    ...rest
));
```